# What is the meaning of the Queen's order?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Queen ordered General to catch a baby. They know nursemaid took and hid the baby.

> But now I have another task for you. Help my daughter to find that
>   tiny, helpless baby that continues somehow to elude **her**.

I didn't understand what is the use of "her" at the end of the sentence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Action verbs in English take a *direct object*. The direct object is always a person or thing that receives the action of the verb.

For example:

> She understood the *book*.
>   He struck the *gong*.
>   They ate *it*.

*Her* in your sentence is the *objective* form of the third person singular feminine pronoun. It serves here as the *direct object* of the verb *elude*.